# Intent Redirection Issue : Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, android-security

I uploaded a build with version v3.3.2 to Google Play Console, which had an issue related to Intent Redirection. Google notified me that this issue must be fixed by May 01, 2023.

I recently uploaded a new build, version v3.4.0, in which I updated the library causing the issue. There are no longer any errors related to Intent Redirection in v3.4.0.

However, I still received a mail for the Intent Redirection error for v3.3.2.

How to resolve this?

**Screenshot:**

[image]